# can linux rmmod command remove all modules?

Tags: linux, drivers

On my system I am insmod'ing a bunch of modules ~7-8, and some have dependencies on others. So I can manually run through an rmmod them in order no problem. I could even write a simple script to do this.

But I am wandering if there is a command like `rmod -all` or somthing that will go through them all removing them in order. I have the feeling there is not a command like this because I have not found it in my search - but if anyone knows of such a command then I would be interested to know about it

Answer (score 0):

Similar to how `modprobe` loads modules together with their dependencies, `modprobe -r` will also unload a module as well as all of its unused dependencies, recursively.